# Помогите изменить парсер

Tags: php

Есть код , который парсит текст и ссылки с определенного адреса.

```
 <?
$html = file_get_contents("https://e-pay.tv/adverts/iframe.php?aff=101305&color=0a97fc&blocks=3&width=400&type=vertical");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
  echo $link->nodeValue.': '.$link->getAttribute("href")."<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

Как изменить так, чтобы получать не весть текст а только то, что заключено в `<h2></h2>`
На выходе получить:
 
заголовок + url
заголовок + url
заголовок + url
`h2` можно получить так `preg_match_all("/<h2?.*>(.*)<\/h2>/", $string, $matches);`
Как связать два этих кода не знаю.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: открыть мануал по htmldomdocument найти что за класс находиться в `$link` от линка взять дочерний элемент `p` и вытащить значение.... А вообще поучить как минимум основы программирования.

Comment: вам там уже ответили как это сделать